# Build a Deep Audio Classifier with Python and Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, speech-recognition, recurrent-neural-network, audio-processing

I have been following Nicholas  'Build a Deep Audio Classifier with Python and Tensorflow"
https://youtu.be/ZLIPkmmDJAc
Our data set is different, my problem consists of recognizing speech with enhanced accuracy even from invalid datasets
and I also got CSV containing texts corresponding to the audio dataset

I dont get it :how to run the CNN model function on Audio files against CSV files